# How to fix blender particle hair explosion

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, particles, hair

Hi I'm not that good with hair particles.
Somehow it explodes, flies off the head and grows into a huge electrostatic ball of wool.

[image]

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5263/

Comment: Hey Riezze, welcome to BSE. The first image you tried to attach didn't work. If you can, please upload a .blend to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ that shows your problem

Comment: oh hi thanks for the tip, i think it worked.hehe

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5263" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5263/)

Comment: You can edit your post to insert that link in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Apply the scale of your object and it will work fine