# Blender stops simulation after 250 frames!

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Blender stops simulation after 250 frames!
As you can see, I changed the end frames in both the scene tab and the physics tab of hair and cloth. (I am sorry I have no idea how to change the language setting, so I circled them in the pictures.)
Furthermore, the bake is also supper slow, I baked for 10 hours and only have 2000 frames completed!   My laptop has AMD Ryzen 9, 16 GB memory, and RTX 3070. I tried my best to fix it but still very slow.

I am so depressed, i waste my days on this! I really appreciate it if there is anyone who can help me out! Thank you, thank you, thank you![image]

Comment: Have you tried to quit Blender and enter the scene again?

Comment: Thanks, BlenderMaster15! I actually figured out just now that I should clear the cache first before running the animation, and it was fixed. However, the cloth and hair start to bomb. I googled and people said it was because the collision distance is under 0.001m . I changed the distance but the explosion still exist. Do you know how to fix it? Thanks again! (similar as https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118451/how-to-fix-blender-particle-hair-explosion)

Comment: Try turning off self-collision in the cloth settings.

Comment: You could consider offsetting the start of the simulation to some amount of frames before the actual shot starts, that way the explosion part has time to sort itself out before the frames you render.

Comment: Turn off self-collision definitely works but the clothes do have 2 layers and it looks wired.

Comment: Thanks Jakemoyo, I solved it by increasing the scale of the models so the collision distances turned out to be relatIvely small. I just have one more question, how long it takes to bake the cloth depends on my laptop settings? like 30 minutes for 1000 frames?